# Change language of some captions in a class derived from scrlttr2 from German to English

Tags: scrlttr2, german, english

I am using a latex class to write a letter that is provided from my (German) university. The letter is in English and I included the English babel as well as write English in the documentclass options. The class is based on scrlttr2.

The proplem is: The date is preceeded by the German word Datum instead of the English Date and at the bottom the page numbering is in German:

Seite 1 von 1

instead of page 1 of 1

I cannot get hold of the author and I opened the cls file and cannot find any option for the language or the said keywords.

I give here an example:

```
\RequirePackage{pdf14}
\documentclass[%
  mustermann,%  Name der zu ladenden .lco-Datei des Autoren
  nexus,%       Schriftart Arial wählen
  English,
  10pt%         gewählte Schriftgröße (standard)
]{tubslttr2}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[english]{babel}% Use option 'english' for english letter
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
     colorlinks,
     citecolor=blue,
     filecolor=black,
     linkcolor=blue,
     urlcolor=blue,
      }


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
  %%% Anschrift %%%
bla bla there
}
\setkomavar{subject}{mySubject}% Betreff-Variable setzen



\opening{Dear people,}

my great message!!

\closing{Yours faithfully,}

%%% optionaler Teil %%%


%\Anlagen{ 
\textbf{Enclosure:}
\begin{itemize}
     \item Something
\end{itemize}
%}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The tubslttr2 file:

```
%%
%% This is file `tubslttr2.cls',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% tubslttr2.dtx  (with options: `class')
%% 
%% This is a generated file.
%% 
%% Copyright (C) 2011 by Tobias Rad and Enrico Jörns
%% 
%% This file may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
%% version 1.2 of this license or (at your option) any later
%% version. The latest version of this license is in:
%% 
%%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% 
%% and version 1.2 or later is part of all distributions of
%% LaTeX version 1999/12/01 or later.
%% 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{tubslttr2}[2011/09/22 v0.1a tubslttr2]
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\newif\ifarial\arialfalse
\RequirePackage{scrbase}
\newif\if@OldKomaVersion
\@ifpackagelater{scrbase}{2011/06/16}{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{%
    tubs,%
    BCOR=0cm,%
    pagenumber=botleft,%
    refline=nodate,%
    backaddress=plain%  Keine Linie unterhalb Rücksendeadresse
  }{scrlttr2}
  \@OldKomaVersionfalse
}{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{%
    tubs,%
    BCOR=0cm,%
    pagenumber=botleft,%
    backaddress=plain%  Keine Linie unterhalb Rücksendeadresse
  }{scrlttr2}
  \@OldKomaVersiontrue
}
\DeclareOptionX{mono}{%
  \PassOptionsToPackage{mono}{tubslogo}
  \PassOptionsToPackage{mono}{tubscolors}
}
\DeclareOptionX{arial}{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{fontsize=10pt}{scrlttr2}
  \arialtrue
}
\DeclareOptionX{nexus}{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{fontsize=11pt}{scrlttr2}
  \arialfalse
}
\DeclareOptionX*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrlttr2}}
\ExecuteOptionsX{nexus}
\ProcessOptionsX
\LoadClass{scrlttr2}[2011/06/16]
\@ifpackagelater{scrbase}{2011/06/16}{}{%
}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `tubslttr2.cls'.
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The example I give at the begining (first code block) is a MWE. I changed English with english, no difference. I get the datum + todays date and at bottom Seite 1 von 1. I am using texlive 2012 on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Tex Live 2012 is very old. But I am sure there is no date and no page number in the result of your MWE. Your class sets the option `refline=nodate` if a KOMA-Script version 3.09a (2011/06/16) is used.  And there is no command to set the page number in footer or header of the first page. Maybe you use a `lco` file that sets some options, loads packages and defines header and/or footer for the first page of the letter?

Comment: Thanks for the tip esdd. I compiled it on a newer version of Texlive and it works as expected.

Comment: @esdd Elke, if I get the reputation for your ideas it is just a completely unintended side effect of getting questions closed. :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by updating the installed TeX system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, we have an answer from esdd: Updating to a current texlive solved the issue. Please accept this answer to delete it from the list of unanswered questions.